# Is there a way to customise `#BUSY` message on custom-function?

Tags: office-js, custom-functions-excel

There are some users of our add-ins started asking for the meaning of `#BUSY` message while custom-function rendering data. Since, our product had a COM add-ins version on excel that showing another message. So, we're looking for a way to change it.

Can we change #BUSY message on custom-function?

Answer (score 1):

No, this message cannot be customized.

Comment: I think it answers the question. It is a "yes or no" question and the answer is "no".

Comment: There may be a possible workaround to this one: What you could do is use a streaming function, with your intermediate state being your custom message. This would still show #busy on first invocation, but would be the string you set afterwards. You would set the string right away, and set a timeout interval, on that interval you would need to return the result and then cancel the interval.